# Is there a way to make tailwindcss work when deployed as an npm module?

Tags: reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

Is there a way to make tailwindcss work when deployed as an npm module?

When TC is executed immediately, it works well. tailwindcss does not work when referencing after npm module deployment.

## TC.js (src/lib)

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import './TC.css';

const TC = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='bg-blue-200'>hello</div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default TC;
```

## TC.css (src/lib)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

## package.json (/)

Dist file was created and distributed with the command below.

```
  "scripts": {
    "publish:npm": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && babel src/lib -d dist --copy-files"
}
```

## import TC

tailwindcss is not working.

```
import React from "react";
import TC "@niceharu/tc";

const Home = () => {
  return (
     <TC></TC>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: I think you also need to import the compiled CSS file from `@niceharu/tc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it works to import the compiled CSS. Thanks. I compiled it using the command below.

```
"scripts": { "build:css": "tailwindcss -o dist/TC.css --minify" }
```